# UITextView, lineHeightMultiple below 1 clips text, clipsToBounds = false doesnt work

Tags: uitextview, nsattributedstring, spacing, clip, nsparagraphstyle

[text is getting clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE3UQ.png) in a UITextView when I set the lineHeightMultiple property to less than 1 in paragraphStyle attribute. setting the clipsToBounds = false for UITextView doesnt seem to have any effect.

I want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhFE9.png)

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.